Experiencing bug with blank pies inside big sunburst chart
We are currently unable to fix this issue with our sunburst chart, where random pieces become blank without labels.
This only happens sometimes when the graph has several splits and lots of results.
We've tried a few different configurations, but are unable to fix the issue.


Could you please provide your config or reproduce the issue in the online demo?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
